# An iOS App how to find all other application on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Bump, Chomp & Appsfire all can list other application on the iPhone, how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=bump+find+other+apps+howto) I found [this link](http://amitay.us/blog/files/how_to_detect_installed_ios_apps.php) quite helpful, it says basically there are two ways to find if **certain** apps are installed without jailbreaking your device:

1. checking if a specific URL scheme is supported by the device => canOpenUrl:
2. comparing the devices currently running processes to known app executable names => sysctl()

Comment: It does work (device-only, no simulator support), I just didn't implement an activity indicator, and it may take a while depending on a number of factors.

Comment: iPhone iOS5 beta7，maybe so slow so I can not wait.

Comment: Daniel Amitay will you open source iHasApp?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer answer you can't without violating the dev agreement and risking app rejection.

There are two methods of doing this (on a non-jailbroken phone):

1. Check to see if custom URL schemes that are known to be used by certain apps are registered as described in http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37103-finding-out-what-apps-installed.html (this allows you to check for certain known apps, not get a list of all installed apps.
2. The way appsfire does with a desktop 'companion' app, that grabs this info from your iTunes and sends it to their server.  (See this article as to why the appsfire developer pulled his app because apple wouldn't approve an update anymore).

Sorry I couldn't be of more help but that's apple!

Comment: All this three can list your app, non-jailbroken and do not need use your iTunes information. Do you try it ?

Comment: No they can't, they use one of the two methods I mention above which are the ONLY way to do this.  The sandbox prohibits access from one app to anything outside of its sandboxed environment. If it appears that way it will just be because they have big databases of URL schemes that various popular apps use, and then test against them as per point 1 above.

Comment: Yes, so as the article that forresty mentions says, you can also look at a list of background process' and compare that against a DB of known apps. However just be aware that this method could be removed or rejected at any time as it uses a private API.

Comment: I already try this way, but I find out so little app run in  background, but appsfire can find more apps at same time.

Comment: @faroligo I don't think sysctl() is a private API

Comment: Ok, well I am just telling you what I know based on my experience of trying to do the same thing.

My understanding is the definition of private api was expanded to undocumented api.  Unless I am missing something, sysctl is not defined in the iPhone developer library and is therefore is a private API. That's not to say you won't get away with using it, as I use it in a number of my apps (for identifying device model), but I am just saying be prepared for your code to break down the line.  Good luck with your search, if you do ever find a method we are all missing come back and let us know!